# compare time between two sequential log entries

Tags: bash, date

I have a log file with following content:

```
01.09.14 14:53:34 UTC 10.10.10.1 RTT was 105ms
01.09.14 14:55:08 UTC 10.10.2.45 RTT was 227ms
01.09.14 14:58:08 UTC 10.10.44.3 RTT was 212ms
01.09.14 14:59:21 UTC 10.10.10.1 RTT was 218ms
01.09.14 15:02:38 UTC 10.10.3.9 RTT was 185ms
01.09.14 15:10:38 UTC 10.10.10.1 RTT was 171ms
01.09.14 15:38:38 UTC 10.10.2.45 RTT was 143ms
```

I would like to compare each line with a next one and in case they are <60 seconds apart, create an entry to a new log file. My idea was to convert the timestamps to suitable input format for date utility, then convert the time to epoch time and finally subtract one value from another. Are there any better or more clever algorithms to achieve the same?

Comment: http://www.unix.com/answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/13785-yesterdays-date-date-arithmetic.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's play a bit with dates:

```
while read -r dat hour rest
do
    secs=$(date -d"${dat//.//} $hour" "+%s")
    [ $((secs - prev)) -ge 60 ] && echo "$dat $hour $rest"
    prev=$secs
done < file > output
```

#### Explanation

- `while read -r dat hour rest` reads every line in three blocks: first one contains the date, second one the hour and the last one the rest of the content.
- `${dat//.//}` converts dots into slashes (`.` --> `/`) in the date field so that `date` will interpret it properly.
- `secs=$(date -d"${dat//.//} $hour" "+%s")` converts the date into seconds since 1 January 1970. This way we will be able to compare each other.
- `[ $((secs - prev)) -ge 60 ] && echo "$dat $hour $rest"` compare current seconds with previous one. If the difference is `g`reater or `e`qual than 60, output the entire line.
- `prev=$secs` store the current seconds for next loop.
- `while read; do ... done < file > output` reads from `file` and outputs into `output` file.

To debug:

```
while read -r dat hour rest
do
    secs=$(date -d"${dat//.//} $hour" "+%s")
    echo "the date in seconds is $secs"
    [ $((secs - prev)) -ge 60 ] && echo "OUTPUT: $dat $hour $rest" > output
    prev=$secs
done < file
```

Returns:

```
$ while read -r dat hour rest; do secs=$(date -d"${dat//.//} $hour" "+%s"); echo "the date in seconds is $secs"; [ $((secs - prev)) -ge 60 ] && echo "OUTPUT: $dat $hour $rest";     prev=$secs; done < file
the date in seconds is 1389275614
the date in seconds is 1389275708
OUTPUT: 01.09.14 14:55:08 UTC 10.10.2.45 RTT was 227ms
the date in seconds is 1389275888
OUTPUT: 01.09.14 14:58:08 UTC 10.10.44.3 RTT was 212ms
the date in seconds is 1389275961
OUTPUT: 01.09.14 14:59:21 UTC 10.10.10.1 RTT was 218ms
the date in seconds is 1389276158
OUTPUT: 01.09.14 15:02:38 UTC 10.10.3.9 RTT was 185ms
the date in seconds is 1389276638
OUTPUT: 01.09.14 15:10:38 UTC 10.10.10.1 RTT was 171ms
the date in seconds is 1389278318
OUTPUT: 01.09.14 15:38:38 UTC 10.10.2.45 RTT was 143ms
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! Am I correct that `-r` in your examples should actually be a flag for `read` and not for `while`? Just for reference, my solution under FreeBSD was `prev=0; while read line; do var=$(date -j -f "%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S" "${line%% UTC*}" "+%s"); (( $((var-prev)) < 60 )) && printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n\n" "Alarms $((var-prev))s apart:" "$prev_line" "$line"; prev=$var; prev_line=$line; done < file.log`

Comment: Yes! My fault, I added the `-r` manually and wasn't very careful :|. Just edited it. Good to read you could solve it and my approach was somehow helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

I would use GNU awk, which has time functions built in

```
awk '
  {
    split($1, d, /[.]/)
    split($2, t, /:/)
    this_t = mktime("20"d[3]" "d[2]" "d[1]" "t[1]" "t[2]" "t[3])
  }
  NR == 1 { print; prev = this_t; next}
  {
    print "elapsed: ", this_t - prev
    print
    prev = this_t
  }
' file
```

```
01.09.14 14:53:34 UTC 10.10.10.1 RTT was 105ms
elapsed:  94
01.09.14 14:55:08 UTC 10.10.2.45 RTT was 227ms
elapsed:  180
01.09.14 14:58:08 UTC 10.10.44.3 RTT was 212ms
elapsed:  73
01.09.14 14:59:21 UTC 10.10.10.1 RTT was 218ms
elapsed:  197
01.09.14 15:02:38 UTC 10.10.3.9 RTT was 185ms
elapsed:  480
01.09.14 15:10:38 UTC 10.10.10.1 RTT was 171ms
elapsed:  1680
01.09.14 15:38:38 UTC 10.10.2.45 RTT was 143ms
```